# Creating ArcMap custom layout that is blank?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, print-templates

In my work i frequently want to print draft maps on A4 or A3, and i want to make a layout template that i can apply to whatever i am doing at the time.
the problem is that the layout templates available either contain too many features (text and legend boxes etc) or are just ridiculous (as in the case of the ISO A4 or A3 templates that have data frame extents that leave a huge blank border around the map).

If i follow any of the help out there i can make a .mxd layout but this includes the data extent and map layers. i dont want to specify this as in a week my data layers may have changed or i am working in another area of the same region.... or somewhere else entirely!

How can i have a standard layout that i can apply to whatever i am working on, that gives me a page size, data frame in relation to the page and simple features like scale bar, north arrow etc?

It is getting iritating changing all this everytime i change page size.

Comment: perhaps you should create your model than just load them, dont have to create new layout every time.

Comment: Hi Florjan, can you explain what you mean by 'model'?

Comment: Create empty layout views and save thet as .mxd, without layers but with all other features, stamps, scale bar, north arrow with different paper size (A3,A4,custom). than while you are working just load one of them under command (layout toolbars/change layout). It is what i do, for evey kind of project i create these models than when a map is needed the model is done no need to create from begin.

Comment: Thanks Florjan, i still have the problem that the data frame resizes to for example, a raster layer. so of course the north arrow and other features must be repositioned once i relocate the data frame. I have no idea why this would even be an option. if i specify the paper size for the layout, why would data be outside of that?